# Static IP on server or router?

Tags: static-ip

I am trying to learn about networking, but I have a question that I can't find a explanatory answer. Basically, I am trying to set-up a server for my local network.

I know, that I have to change the setting from DHCP to STATIC, but I don't know if that should be done on my router or on my server? Or maybe both?

Also what is the difference between these two?

Thanks for your answers, you rock!

Comment: On the server. Just make sure that it doesn't sit in the range that the router hands DHCP leases out on, you wouldn't want IP collisions on your network.  As for the difference between DHCP & static... my friend google found this link for you:  http://superuser.com/questions/194473/difference-between-static-and-dhcp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it a few different ways actually.  Server or the router. Or a combo of both. It depends on what suits your needs & comfort level better.

1. You could setup DHCP with a static IP on the server.  Very easy.
2. You could setup the router to always assign the same IP address for a specific MAC address. Slightly more complicated, but works well.
3. 100% pure static IP on the server. Just turn off DHCP & manually enter all network settings. This is not as hard as it sounds & in my experience this works well in all environments.